# How do prevent an image animation from crossing across my whole screen and not just my container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have currently have a script function which takes an image and creates an animation which allows it to pass from one side of the screen to another. However i just want the animation to go across my container which is significantly smaller than the screen size. How do i change the code to allow it to do this?

Function:

```
 <script>
        $(function() {
            var img = $("#bus"),
                    width = img.get(0).width,
                    screenWidth = $(window).width(),
                    duration = 10000;

            function animateBus() {
                img.css("left", -width)
                        .animate({
                            "left": screenWidth
                        }, duration, animateBus);
            }

            animateBus();
        });

    </script>
```

This is my Container also:

```
div.container {
            text-align: left;
            width: 710px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 12px solid black;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
```

Comment: have you try to change `screenWidth = $(window).width()` with `screenWidth = $("div.container").width()` ?

Comment: Of course i have doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Change `screenWidth = $(window).width(),` to `screenWidth = $("div.container").width(),`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using css3 animations...

```js
$(window).ready(function() {

  $('#animate').on('click', function() {
    $('.bus').addClass('animate');
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.bus {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% - 100px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: slide 2s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation: slide 2s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  100% {
    right: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes slide {
  100% {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img class="bus animate" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>
```

Comment: But i dont want a button? i want it to do it automatically?

Comment: No problem! we can simply add the class to the img  element itself, look at the update

Comment: This doesnt work, i want to place an image there not text. Even when i add an image it just still goes to the full side off the screen and not within the container

Comment: @user7048814 Here i updated it, notice that where `calc(100% - 100px);` the `100px` is the width of the image

Comment: OKay it works with the button, but how about without? that was the whole point in the question

Comment: You done need the button all you need to do is add the class

Comment: And it doesn't use the button, it just has a delay

Comment: @user7048814 I removed the button, the animation is executed on elements with the class animate...

Comment: The function at the top, has to been enclosed in <Script> yeah?

Comment: It's JavaScript, so yes , you can also createa separate JavaScript file and include it, you really need to look into the basics first...